# Cannot access the foreignkey data in datatables

Tags: django, datatables

I have provided the javascript below. Please note the one with name "teacher". This teacher is basically a foriegn key. However when I try to console.log the row, it doesnt show me that particular array value as an object or the data returned as an object and instead it returns a string since it uses `def __str__` on django models.
Hence im not able to get the particular value, i.e `teacher.first_name` or in this case `data.first_name` which results `undefined`

P.S. Im using [django-datatables-view](https://pypi.org/project/django-datatables-view/1.19.1/) for providing the ajax url.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
      $('.table').DataTable({
        "columnDefs": [
          {
            name: 'date_created',
            orderable: true,
            searchable: true,
            targets: [0],
          },
          {
            name: 'name',
            orderable: true,
            searchable: true,
            targets: [1],
          },
          {
            name: 'email',
            orderable: true,
            searchable: true,
            targets: [2],
          },
          {
            name: 'phone',
            orderable: true,
            searchable: true,
            targets: [3],
          },
          {
            name: 'course',
            orderable: true,
            searchable: true,
            targets: [4],
          },
          {
            name: 'remarks',
            orderable: true,
            searchable: true,
            targets: [5],
          },
          {
            name: 'teacher',
            orderable: true,
            searchable: true,
            targets: [6],
            render: function(data, type, row){
              return data.first_name + "<br>(" + data + ")" 
            }
          },
          {
            name: 'is_enrolled',
            orderable: true,
            searchable: true,
            targets: [7],
            render: function(data, type, row){
              if (data === "True"){
                return "<i class='fa fa-check text-success text'></i>"
              }
              else{
                return "<i class='fa fa-times text-danger text'></i>"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            name: 'status',
            orderable: true,
            searchable: true,
            targets: [8],
          },
          {
            name: 'get_lead.owner',
            orderable: true,
            searchable: true,
            targets: [9],
          },
        ],
        order: [],
        "processing": true,
        "language": {
            processing: '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span> '},
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "{% url 'referrals-json' %}",
        scrollY: 500,
        dom : 'flrBtip',
        searchHighlight: true,
        buttons : [
          { extend: 'excel', text: 'Export', className: 'btn-primary' }
        ],
        "lengthMenu": [ [10,50,100,-1], [10,50,100,"All"] ]
      });
    } );
```

[EDIT] Adding more info to clear things out.
On doing a console.log of row and data, i.e

```
render: function(data, type, row){
    console.log(row, data)
}
```

I get the following result. Observe the 6th array element which is a string and not an object.

```
Array(10) [ "2021-10-16 06:25:36+00:00", "Vibula", "testmail@gmail.com", "96779*****", "EMAESTER", "He/She is IT by profession || Looking for online teaching Job", "anotheremail@gmail.com", "False", "Not Dialed", "" ]
​
0: "2021-10-16 06:25:36+00:00"
​
1: "Vibula"
​
2: "testmail@gmail.com"
​
3: "96779*****"
​
4: "EMAESTER"
​
5: "He/She is IT by profession || Looking for online teaching Job"
​
6: "anotheremail@gmail.com"
​
7: "False"
​
8: "Not Dialed"
​
9: ""
​
length: 10
​
<prototype>: Array []
 anotheremail@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I had completely missed that the library provides a method i.e 'render_column' that does the exact same thing render option does in the datatables jquery section.
This is what I did:

```
def render_column(self, row, column):
        # We want to render teacher as a custom column
        if column == 'teacher':
            print row.teacher.first_name, row.teacher.email
            # escape HTML for security reasons
            return '{0}<br>({1})'.format(row.teacher.first_name, row.teacher.email)
        else:
            return super(ReferralsJSON, self).render_column(row, column)
```